# Scrapy Spider Returns Only White Space Characters

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data from the following URL:

https://www.cheyennecity.org/Jobs.aspx?UniqueId=86&From=Professional-86&CommunityJobs=False&JobID=Senior-Planning-Technician-MPO-933

I've been using the scrapy shell command, so I could debug the responses I was getting back from crawling the site.

When I'm using the `response.css('#divSideBar div h3').get(default='')` in the terminal, I get an empty response. I ended up going up a level with the following selector... `response.css('#divSideBar').get(default='')` and I get a bunch of white space characters `\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t`

I can select the elements just fine with the developer tools in Chrome. I checked the network tab in Chrome as well and the content is coming from the URL I'm scraping:

[image]

Is there a way to access the contents of the element with the `#divSideBar` id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually all the data is coming from an dynamic `post` request.

What you need to do is send the another `FormRequest` with some essential `parameter` as per the request which you can see in the *inspect Network header tab*.

```
def parse(self, response):
   target_headers = {
        'Accept'         : '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4',
        'Connection'     : 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Type'   : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'User-Agent'     : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
                          AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36',
        'Referer'        : request.url,
    }

   yield FormRequest(request.url, formdata={...}, method='POST', 
                     headers=target_headers, meta=response.meta, callback=self.parse_detail)

def parse_detail(self, response):
    # crawl your data here
```

Comment: I looked at the request headers after I posted my question and saw that! Thank you!